# How to know whether a process ended in JBPM

Tags: jbpm

Started a Jbpm process through StatefulKnowledgeSeesion(ksession)

```
    ksession.startProcess(processName);
```

Now I want to know, whether the process ended.
How to get the end status ?..Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be notified when the process ended you can register your own listener (which extends *org.drools.core.event.DefaultProcessEventListener* or implement the *org.kie.api.event.process.ProcessEventListener* interface), and implement the "afterProcessCompleted" method:

```
@Override
public void afterProcessCompleted(ProcessCompletedEvent event) {

    org.kie.api.runtime.process.ProcessInstance processInstance = event
            .getProcessInstance();
    log.info("Process completed: processId=["
            + processInstance.getProcessId() + "]; processInstanceId=["
            + processInstance.getId() + "]");
}
```

Check [Event Listeners from documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMCoreEngine.html#d0e1816)

Comment: I was writing exactly the same answer while the notification that a new answer was posted popup in here :). A second option is to get hold of the ProcessInstance from the ksession, but that is not usually recommended for persistent processes.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do ksession.getProcessInstance(id).  If the process is completed, that will return **null** (as completed process instances are no longer required for execution, note that information about the execution of the process instance is still available in the audit log of course).